# Datepicker Jquery disable specific dates - Gravity Forms - WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

Hi I am trying to set the datepicker to grey out selected dates but have had a hard time figuring out why it's not working I have searched google found code but none that seem to work.. with WordPress anyway?

The code I have currently is displayed below it currently greys out weekends and the selectable days are tomorrows date.

If anyone can help that'd be fantastic and much respect!

My code so far!

I have tried all of the other posts that claim to work but doesn't work with WordPress.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({ 
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends, 
    minDate: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' 
  });
});
```

Comment: Put the dates you want to disable in an array and compare them in `beforeShowDay`. See the duplicate for the exact implementation

Comment: It isn't the same thing though..